# I am stuck on boot menu Lenovo IdeaPad Windows 11 and Kubuntu dual boot

Tags: boot, grub, lenovo-laptop, windows-11, kubuntu

I am on Windows 11 and I dual booted Kubuntu (that is not a typo). I didn't like it much so I deleted it through the Disk Management tool in Windows. But now it is still trying to load Kubuntu. I was stuck at the "Grub menu", but I got out of that and came to boot menu, though, nothing happened when I chose Windows boot loader. It just went of for a 3-4 frames and came back to the boot menu.
Any help would be appreciated. If you need any more details let me know since this is my first question here.

Comment: Did you check the related answers at the right side of this page?

Comment: I checked it right now but none of it is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the other laptop to flash the iso image to a pendrive and booted from it. It worked on one specific usb port. I could have used the same laptop and flash it but anyway now I have windows in it.